# Web view Video streaming in android?

Tags: android, url, android-webview

I use the following code to play the Video from remote server,

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.loadUrl("http://commonsware.com/misc/test2.3gp");
```

its not playing the Video, while if i put the link in browser it will working fine.What mistake i made i don`t know.Even i also put internet access permission in manifest file.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your problem solved? I am also stuck into this problem. If your problem is solved then can you post here your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
wv.loadUrl("http://commonsware.com/misc/test2.3gp");
```